# Timout when trying to connect to couchbase in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, timeout, couchbase

I have a running couchbase instance in my kubernetes cluster which is exposed using ingress with host url : example.com.

I used the following yaml files to deploy couchbase in kubernetes.

**Master:**

```
apiVersion: v1  
kind: ReplicationController  
metadata:  
  name: couchbase-master-rc
spec:  
  replicas: 1  
  selector:  
    app: master-pod  
  template:  
    metadata:  
      labels:  
        app: master-pod  
    spec:  
      containers:  
      - name: couchbase-master  
        image: arungupta/couchbase:k8s 
        env:  
          - name: TYPE  
            value: MASTER  
        ports:  
        - containerPort: 8091 
---
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Service  
metadata:   
  name: couchbase-master-service  
  labels:   
    app: couchbase-master-service  
spec:   
  ports:  
    - port: 8091  
  selector:   
    app: master-pod  
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**Worker:**

```
apiVersion: v1  
kind: ReplicationController  
metadata:  
  name: couchbase-worker-rc  
spec:  
  replicas: 1  
  selector:  
    app: couchbase-worker-pod  
  template:  
    metadata:  
      labels:  
        app: couchbase-worker-pod  
    spec:  
      containers:  
      - name: couchbase-worker  
        image: arungupta/couchbase:k8s  
        env:  
          - name: TYPE  
            value: "WORKER"  
          - name: COUCHBASE_MASTER  
            value: "couchbase-master-service"  
          - name: AUTO_REBALANCE  
            value: "false"  
        ports:  
        - containerPort: 8091
```

**Ingress:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: couchbase
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: couchbase-master-service
          servicePort: 8091
```

I am able to see the UI and work on it as shown in the image:
[image]

But when I try to connect it from visual studio it gives me a timeout exception.

```
var cluster = new Cluster(new ClientConfiguration
            {
                Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri("http://example.com") }
            });
            var authenticator = new PasswordAuthenticator("ua_user", "ua_password");
            cluster.Authenticate(authenticator);
            //Create bucket
            var clusterManager = cluster.CreateManager();


            var result = clusterManager.CreateBucket("TEST");
```

Comment: Could you help add your Ingress definition file and the hosts file where you add example.com entry with the local Ingress IP?

Comment: Added the yaml files used for deployment. This deployment is for my company so I wont be able to relieve the actual host url. And stackoverflow restricted me from giving it anything other than example.com.

Comment: am I right that you are checking UI and truing to connect with the VisualStudio from the same machine (so it's not a DNS issue) ?

Comment: I'd recommend not using arungupta/couchbase:k8s, this is a non-official image that is probably out of date. Also, I'd recommend using the Couchbase operator for kubernetes deployments: https://couchbase.com/products/cloud/kubernetes